# Angular JS GET http://localhost:8000/houses/houses.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, json

So I hit a big bump and I didn't find an answer anywhere.
I'm trying to get a list of JSON files and show them with Angular JS.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="estateApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Case</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.animations.css" /> 

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js">  </script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.config.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.animations.js"></script> 
<script src="core/core.module.js"></script>
<script src="core/checkmark/checkmark.filter.js"></script>
<script src="core/house/house.module.js"></script>
<script src="core/house/house.service.js"></script>
<script src="house-list/house-list.module.js"></script>
<script src="house-list/house-list.component.js"></script>
<script src="house-detail/house-detail.module.js"></script>
<script src="house-detail/house-detail.component.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="view-container">
  <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular service:

```
'use strict';
angular.
module('core.house').
factory('House', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
  return $resource('houses/:houseId.json', {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {houseId: 'houses'},
      isArray: true
    }
  });
 }
]);
```

JSON example:

```
{
"name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
"utilities": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
],
"finishes": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
],
"end": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
],
"other-details": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
],
"location":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"Price": "37.000 Euro", 
"id": "house-1", 
"images": [
    "images/houses/casa-1.0", 
    "images/houses/casa-1.1", 
    "images/houses/casa-1.2", 
    "images/houses/casa-1.3", 
    "images/houses/casa-1.4"
],  
"rooms":"3",
"area":"54 mp",
"partitioning":"circular",
"confort":"1",
"floor":"3/4",
"bathrooms":"1",
"balconies":"1"
 }
```

And the template:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <!--Sidebar content-->

   <p>
    Cauta:
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.query" />
   </p>

   <p>
    Sorteaza:
    <select ng-model="$ctrl.orderProp">
      <option value="name">Alfabetic</option>
    </select>
   </p>

 </div>
 <div class="col-md-10">
  <!--Body content-->

  <ul class="houses">
     <li ng-repeat="house in $ctrl.houses |
   filter:$ctrl.query | 
    orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp" class="thumbnail house-list-item">
      <a href="#!/houses/{{house.id}}" class="thumb">
        <img ng-src="{{house.imageUrl}}" alt="{{house.name}}" />
      </a>
      <a href="#!/houses/{{house.id}}">{{house.name}}</a>
      <p>{{house.price}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I will provide any other files on request, I just don't know what to provide for the moment.

It's from the angular tutorial on their site, strange, but there it works with their JSONs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what `.json` files actually do exist?

Comment: it's only one at the moment, but I can't seem to be able to read even that.

Comment: But is that the path you expect it to be?

Comment: yup, I checked the path like 30 times during the 2 hours i tried to debug this, everything seems in order...

Comment: Simple trick many forget to try while debugging ajax is simply open that in browser address bar. Server config issue it sounds like

Comment: it opens in the browser with that path, so the JSON is where I want it, the thing is that in order to get the whole list of JSON files I needed to make that function from the service. I think that the function is not working correctly.